# UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification called multiple time swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

I am creating app which play youtube video.

In this app,

User can play youtube video and when user go background or lock phone then sound of video will play

I am use `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` to play background video and i am not remove `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`in `viewDidDisappear` because i want to play video sound whole app

here is code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)

      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playBgVideo", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
 } 

 func playBgVideo()
 {
   bgTimer =  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "hello", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playFgVideo", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
 }

 func hello()
 {
  player?.play()
 }

 func playFgVideo()
{
 bgTimer?.invalidate()
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)


}
```

When i play video first time then background play work perfectly because of `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` called once,but i play second video then background play not work because `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` called twice

give me suggestion how can i solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What's the timer for? How many times are you adding an observer?

Comment: Might be you add and remove notification in viewDidLoad. If your view not deallocating, viewDidLoad never fire again. Try to add notification in viewWillAppear and remove viewWillDisappear.

Comment: i cannot remove notification in viewWillDisappear because it's require for whole app

Comment: @Wain i am only add observer one time in viewDidLoad

Comment: @John do you mind to share your solution if you have solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to set a breakpoint at `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)` and make sure that `self` has the same in-memory address (it will have different, I think). Generally, that means:

1. When you enter `viewDidLoad()`, you unregister a non-existing
   observer (but you should have an exception).
2. You register `self` which is then retained by the timer. And it all repeats.

P.S. In general, it looks like you expect `dealloc` to be called so that you can perform a cleanup or you don't handle dealloc at all.

Comment: All right. A) Set a breakpoint inside viewDidLoad. B) Implement dealloc on your view conroller and set a breakpoint inside. C) Invalidate and nullify the timer in dealloc.

Comment: dealloc/deinit not called in swift

Comment: Sorry, I meant "deinit". OK, if it isn't called, your VC is not deallocated.

Comment: invalidate timer when app in foreground  code updated checked without use of deinit